# Implementing JSON Library Java - ToString function

Tags: java, json, tostring

I'm working on a lab assignment and for the first part I need to implement a simple JSON library so I can export JSON data in Java.

Now I'm stuck on the JSONobject toString() function;

The library should could export the JSON model to a textual representation so it can be stored in a file, or transferred using HTTP therefor I need to use the toString method

but with I have already I get errors, can someone help me with the toString function

This is my JsonObject class :

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class JsonObject extends LinkedHashMap<String, JsonValue> implements JsonValue {


   @Override
   public JsonObject asObject(){

       return this;
   }

   public void put(String key, int i){

       JsonPrimitive jsonprim = new JsonPrimitive(i);
       this.put(key, jsonprim);


   }

   public void put(String key, boolean b){

         JsonPrimitive jsonprim = new JsonPrimitive(b);
       this.put(key, jsonprim);

   }
   public void put(String key, double d){

         JsonPrimitive jsonprim = new JsonPrimitive(d);
       this.put(key, jsonprim);

   }

  public void put(String key, String string){

        JsonPrimitive jsonprim = new JsonPrimitive(string);
       this.put(key, jsonprim);

   }

  public JsonValue get(String key){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Cannot return JsonValue of type " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "as string");

  }

  public boolean has(String key) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Cannot return JsonValue of type " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "as string");

  }

  public JsonValue get(int index) {
     return this.get(index);
  }
```

And here is the toString where i'm stuck on

```
public String toString() {

      return this.toString();
  }
}
```

& The main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Create a nested JSON object containing user records
        JsonArray userRecords = new JsonArray();
        userRecords.add(new JsonObjectBuilder()
              .add("id", 1)
               .add("name", "John Doe")
                .add("address", new JsonObjectBuilder()
                      .add("street", "Abbey Road")
                       .add("number", 7)
                       .add("city", "London"))
               .build());

    userRecords.add(new JsonObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", 2)
            .add("name", "Jane Doe")
            .add("address", new JsonObjectBuilder()
                    .add("street", "Abbey Road")
                    .add("number", 8)
                    .add("city", "London"))
            .build());

    //Print the records
    System.out.println(userRecords);

    //Retrieve the address of the first user
    System.out.println(userRecords.get(0).get("address"));
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the actual outcome and what did you expect instead?

Comment: i should get the json code for the records I hardcoded in the main, but I can build the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your error "java.lang.StackOverflowError"?

If so, your toString() method is the cause. You are writing

```
public String toString() {
      return this.toString();
  }
}
```

It should be like this

```
public String toString() {
      return super.toString();
  }
}
```

or some other implementation. (at least, don't call this.toString())

Because "this" here points your JsonObject class and this.toString() is this method itself.

So calling this.toString() in toString() method cause infinit method call.

Comment: if its just `return super.toString();`, so don't override it at all.

Comment: I just wanted to say "calling this.toString() in toString() method is wrong". Maybe here needs some other implementation.

Comment: Thanks ! But the error is

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Labo1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]